# Is there an O(n^2) algorithm to get the n-th (or 3rd) power of an upper triangular matrix?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity

I'm trying to calculate the amount of lenght 3 paths in a directed graph with a adjacency matrix of the form:

$M = \begin{bmatrix}  0      & a_{12} & a_{13} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
                  \vdots & \ddots & a_{23} & \cdots & a_{2n} \\
                  0      &        & 0      & \cdots & a_{3n} \\
                  \vdots &        &        & \ddots & \vdots \\
                  0      & \dots  & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Where $a_{ij}$ is either $1$ or $0$.

I can do it by finding $M^{3}$, so is there any algorithm that i can use to find $M^3$ at most in $O(n^2)$?

Comment: Since your matrix is *strictly* upper triangular, you could modify the loop [here](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~rizos/papers/ics97/node11.html) to account for the zero diagonal, and then use that in a [binary powering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) method.

Comment: @J.M.isapoormathematician Already did this but run time is still too long

Comment: Then perhaps you should edit your post to mention how large your matrices are.

Comment: @J.M.isapoormathematician Why does that matter? $O(n^2)$ is $O(n^2)$, and your method is definitely $O(n^3)$: count the loops.

Comment: @Misha, if the matrices aren't terribly large, that shouldn't take too long as the OP claims.

Comment: @J.M.isapoormathematician They range in size from 2 to 2000, they are for a google coding challenge named google foobar. Go check it in my [github](https://github.com/upeguiborja/g.foo.bar/) it is under _find-the-acess-codes_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want is the number of paths, then you don't need to compute $M^3$; all you need is $\mathbf 1^{\mathsf T}M^3 \mathbf 1$, where $\mathbf 1$ is the all-ones vector.

So you can compute $\mathbf u = M\mathbf 1$ in $O(n^2)$ time, and similarly compute $\mathbf v = M \mathbf u$, $\mathbf w = M \mathbf v$, and finally get $\mathbf 1^{\mathsf T}\mathbf w$ as your final answer.

Comment: LAPACK has specific methods for multiplying a triangular matrix with a vector, and they can even account for the matrix being *strictly* triangular.

Comment: Will try to implement this solution and test if it's O[n^2], those LAPACK subroutines are hard to read `SUBROUTINE STRMV(UPLO,TRANS,DIAG,N,A,LDA,X,INCX)` for people not knowing fortran so i will implement a naive vector times matrix multiplication algorithm in python.

Comment: Naive matrix-vector multiplication should work just fine. (The fancy specific method for triangular matrices is to write a loop that skips the elements below the diagonal, and this only saves you a factor of $2$ in the running time.)

Comment: Actually the problem was to find lenght 2 paths (paths with 3 vertices). But your solution scaled anyway, and it overperforms the path walk algorithm i implemented which is only O[^2] to finding lenght 2 paths, this is O[n^2] to find any lenght paths. Nice one

Comment: Size 500 Matrix with all 1s (upper triangular) -> **Alternative O[n^3] with optimizations**: 272.83s ||| **Graph walk solution with O[n^2]**: 9.15s |||
**misha-lavrov suggestion with O[n^2]**: 10.64s